# When using setWrapperSize in Swiper the banner slides disappear in RTL

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have a page that is in RTL mode ( `<html lang="en" dir="rtl">` ) and the below init for Swiper JS, but the slides of the banners are invisible just when in RTL mode. When in LTR mode they are visible. I'm using the latest version of the library.

If I remove setWrapperSize: true they become visible again, but new sizing issues are created during load.

How can I keep setWrapperSize: true and not have the issue with invisible slides?

I've tried setWrapperSize: true with the demo RTL example from the swiperjs site and the same issue occurs in RTL, but not in LTR mode. See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/u5ay628c/1/.

I can see the reason the slides aren't showing is they are getting the incorrect translate3d values. This seems like a bug? Any ideas around it?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up fixing it with CSS. Flipped the carousel to lrt when in rtl and then flipped the pagination dots to rtl.

Comment: how? I need some help in it